# MasterPage Renders the dropdown menu only when fired from VS2008 but IIS the menu looks jacked up

Tags: html, css, asp.net, iis

I have an Web Application that contains a masterpage which contains drop-down menu and 39 content pages, the application looks jacked up from VS2008 without clicking the option to view in browser however when i do the view in browser the application looks fine. let me explain with pictures:

1) MasterPage from VS2008 with out browsing:

[image]

2) When Viewed from the LocalHost/browser:

[image]

3) When i hosted the application and ran the application:

[image]

My guess is something wrong with the css not getting applied to the html, but i am not sure how to get this change done on the master-page

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!
The Style Sheet

```
/* Menu */
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
    nav ul {
    background: #FFF4D5; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #FFF4D5 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFF4D5 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

    nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #663300;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #663300 0%, #663300 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #663300 0%, #663300 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #663300 0%,#663300 40%);
    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #00FFFF;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
        color: #FFF4D5; text-decoration: none;
    }

nav ul ul {
    background: #663300; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
        position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 40px;
            color: #663300;
        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #FFF4D5;
            }
    nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}       

#nav {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 36px;
    float: left;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 24px 0 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.menu 
{
list-style: none;
width: 1068px;
margin: 5px auto 0 auto;
padding-left: 30px;
background: #682E00 url('images/menu-bg.gif') repeat-x 0 0;
}
.menu ul li a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#EBE0D5;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:181px; 
    height:42px; 
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom: 0;
    background-image:url('image1/brown/center.png');
    line-height:48px; 
    font-size:11px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
.menu .left_nosub {
    background-image:url('image1/brown/left.png');
    padding-left: 1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
}
.menu .right_hassub {
    background-image:url('image1/brown/right.png');
}
.menu .right_nosub {
    background-image:url('image1/brown/right.png');
}
.menu ul {padding:0; margin:0; list-style: none;
    width: 1100px;
}
.menu ul li {float:left; position:relative;
    top: 13px;
    left: 3px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 179px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.menu ul li ul {display: none;}

.menu ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #D2C6AC;
}

.menu ul li ul li:first-child {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.menu ul li ul li:last-child {
   border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Button ":hover" Styling */
.menu ul li:hover a {color:#66FFFF; background:url('image1/brown/left_nosub.png') center top no-reapeat;}
.menu ul li:hover ul {display:block; position:absolute; top:29px; left:0; width:152px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.menu ul li:hover ul li a.center_hassub {background:#6a3; color:#EBE0D5;}
.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover a.center_hassub {background:#6fc; color:#381B01;}
.menu ul li:hover ul li ul {display: none;}

.menu ul li:hover .left_nosub {color:#381B01; background:url('image1/brown/left_nosub.png');}
.menu ul li:hover .right_hassub {color:#381B01; background:url('image1/brown/right_hassub.png') ;}
.menu ul li:hover .right_nosub {color:#381B01; background:url('image1/brown/right_nosub.png') ;}

/* DropDown Styling */
.menu ul li:hover ul li a {background-image: none; display:block;height: 28px; line-height: 26px; color:#381B01; width:126px; text-align:left; margin: 0; padding:0 13px;font-weight:normal;}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0 0 15px;
    width: 152px;
}
```

The HTML

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NetWeightApp.master.cs" Inherits="NetWeightWebApp.NetWeightApp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>NetWeightProgram</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection, tv" />
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-ie.css" media="screen, projection, tv" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-ie6.css" media="screen, projection, tv" /><![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="top">&nbsp;</div>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
<div class="wrapper">
      <h1 style="color: #FFFFFF"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Net Weight Application</h1>

        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MasterData</a>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="NtWtMasterData.aspx">Net Wt Master Data</a></li>
                        <li><a href= "PrintOvrpkReport.aspx">Print Ovrpk % Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="HistoricalOverPack.aspx">Historical Overpack %</a></li>
                        <li><a href="PrintAllMasterData.aspx">Print All Mstr Data</a></li>
                        <li><a href="FindMissingData.aspx">Find Missing Data</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="ItemUPCXREF.aspx">Item/UPC XREF</a></li>       
                        </ul>

            <li><a href="#">ProductWeightDataSheets</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Print One Item</a>
                                <ul>
    <li><a href = "PrintOneBag.aspx" >Bag</a></li>

                         <li><a href = "PrintOneBar.aspx">Bar</a></li>

                          <li><a href = "PrintOneSapal.aspx">Sapal</a></li>

                           <li><a  href = "PrintOneHandPack.aspx">Hand Pack</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Print All Items</a>
                        <ul>
                         <li><a  href = "AllBag.aspx">Bag</a></li>
                         <li><a  href = "AllBar.aspx">Bar</a></li>
                          <li><a href = "PrintAllSapal.aspx">Sapal</a></li>
                           <li><a href = "PrintAllHandPack.aspx">Hand Pack</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">PieceSizeAndWeightDataSheet</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">PrintPieceSpecSheet</a>
                                <ul>
    <li><a tabindex = "-1"  href = "PieceCode.aspx">Center</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "piececodeweightcontrol.aspx">Center W/ Inclusions</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "PieceWeightControlFinished.aspx">Finshed Piece </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            <li><a href="#">DailyTrackingDataInput</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">PrintTrackingRepport</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "EnterData.aspx">EnterDailyData </a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "DailyTrackingBag.aspx">Bag </a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "DailyTrackingSapal.aspx">Sapal </a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "DailyTrackingHandPack.aspx">HandPack </a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "NetWeightDiscrepancies.aspx">NetWeightDiscrepancies </a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "labelweight.aspx">LabelWeightDiscrepancies </a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "Net_Weight_Tracking_Data_by_Unit.aspx">DisplayTrackingDataByUPC</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </li>               
            <li><a href="#">Savings</a>
        <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Raw Materials</a>
                                <ul>
    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "RmSavings.aspx">Total</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "RmSavingsbyUnitUpc.aspx">ByUnitUPC</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "RmSavingsByshift.aspx">ByShift</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "rmsavingsbydate.aspx">ByDate</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "RmSavingsByMonthWeek.aspx">ByWeek</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Labor</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "labortotal.aspx">Total</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "LaborsavingsProduction.aspx">By Prd Line</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "LaborSavingsDate.aspx">By Date</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">EnterData</a>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="LaborSavings.aspx" >LaborSavings</a></li>
                        <li><a href= "Location.aspx" >Location</a></li>
                        <li><a href="MaximumAllowableVariations.aspx" >MaximumAllowableVariations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="NetMasterData.aspx" >NetWeightMasterData</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Net Weight Tracking.aspx">Net Weight Tracking</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="OverPackPercentage.aspx" >OverPackPercentages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ProductGroups.aspx" >ProductGroups</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="ProductionLines.aspx" >ProductionLines</a></li>    
                        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky are you talking about the html and css code i have attached it above!!

Comment: Yes, but where are you linking the CSS file

Comment: The `<head>` part with the actual `<link>`s referring to the CSS files would be useful. And also the directories of the HTML file and the CSS file.

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky i have added the css link in the html code above

Comment: How did you manage to get `css/style.css` linked thrice?!

Comment: @Xufox I have added the head and link in the above html, what do you mean by directories of the html and css file?

Comment: What directory are your files stored in? What directory is your HTML file in? Is your CSS file in the same directory as the HTML file or is it in the folder `css/` named `style.css`?

Comment: @Xufox i have a folder called css in my solution explorer and the inside that i have style.css

Comment: And do you have the exact folder structure recreated and CSS file copied to wherever you are hosting this?

Comment: @Xufox i dont have an .html file any where in the project that is strange, i beleive i just did a edit on index.html on my notepad++ copied the code over pasted it on the masterpage and then added my style sheet to it.

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky yes i checked my webserver for the css file and its all there, same structure

Comment: what about style-ie.css? is that also there?

Comment: Use the network tab of your browser to inspect the page when running from IIS. I think you'll see some incorrect paths to the CSS and 404's. Probably you need to make your CSS paths application root relative.

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky your right it does seem to be an browser issue, when i ran it on chrome it rendered correctly but in ie its causing the issue, but when i opened the style-ie.css it only has some modification to images on the web template but i dont have any images on my web app so that is not the case.